Why does scikit's cross-validation return a negative R^2 for my strongly correlated data
I have exactly the following preprocessed data in a small Pandas dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'protesters_estimate': [-0.025277219233618427,  -1.1209981799804989, -0.7584382556131943, 0.3357505651218889, -0.4730177055285195, -1.0359399607957092, 0.4222519531704431, 0.3686864558273824, -0.3912614033608771, 3.4038543116306723, -0.7557908523751271, 0.8585956431868133, -0.36278846361162215, -0.7752270840612929, 1.434618254960961, -0.5714029624055086, 0.42736811052416984, -0.13314848352841915, -0.7043146521442091, 0.9568348193244159, -0.37506384503413215, -0.7252910460740197],

'climate_mentions': [0.014620553379808637, 0.014523096436234, 0.009729460025372921, 0.019436345966958212, 0.017640028535268398, 0.011277283001333295, 0.019327228087934106, 0.015160273972011584, 0.021741381095351484, 0.03670954832162733, 0.005625206385871155, 0.02724524233334451, 0.008399949825246915, 0.012832028743744384, 0.015122959766868112, 0.009519105767012719, 0.012243145968000543, 0.02004639571430332, 0.016822301175172555, 0.012241593155590624, 0.004016740988627743, 0.01021722632961321]})

When I run df.corr() I get a correlation of 0.7 between the two variables. But when I run the following code (with sklearn):
X = df[['protesters_estimate']]
y = df['climate_mentions']
print(f"Cross val score: {cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y).mean()}")

I get the output 'Cross val score: -0.4412345093041985'.
What is going on here? As I understand it, R^2 should be literally (0.7)^2 for a linear regression like this, and if there's some noise introduced by the cross-val split you'd expect it to be +- a decimal place or two, not a negative score.
To further confuse me, if I actually train and interrogate the model:
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print(f"R-squared: {model.score(X, y)}") 

I get basically the output I expect: 'R-squared: 0.48415257262102906'

Do you know the equation used to calculate $R^2$ in your code and if it involves the Pearson correlation? (Hint: no, sklearn does not make explicit use of the Pearson correlation to calculate $R^2$, and negative values re totally possible.)

I coded an experiment in R that uses your data and does some cross-validation by hand.
(Okay, I didn't quite do cross-validation, but it is repeated use of different holdout sets to see how the out-of-sample $R^2$ behaves.)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
x <- c(-0.025277219233618427,  -1.1209981799804989, -0.7584382556131943, 0.3357505651218889, -0.4730177055285195, -1.0359399607957092, 0.4222519531704431, 0.3686864558273824, -0.3912614033608771, 3.4038543116306723, -0.7557908523751271, 0.8585956431868133, -0.36278846361162215, -0.7752270840612929, 1.434618254960961, -0.5714029624055086, 0.42736811052416984, -0.13314848352841915, -0.7043146521442091, 0.9568348193244159, -0.37506384503413215, -0.7252910460740197)
y <- c(0.014620553379808637, 0.014523096436234, 0.009729460025372921, 0.019436345966958212, 0.017640028535268398, 0.011277283001333295, 0.019327228087934106, 0.015160273972011584, 0.021741381095351484, 0.03670954832162733, 0.005625206385871155, 0.02724524233334451, 0.008399949825246915, 0.012832028743744384, 0.015122959766868112, 0.009519105767012719, 0.012243145968000543, 0.02004639571430332, 0.016822301175172555, 0.012241593155590624, 0.004016740988627743, 0.01021722632961321)
n_train <- 17
ncv <- 75
r2_sklearn <- function(y, yhat){
  num <- sum((y - yhat)^2)
  den <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
  return(1 - (num/den))
}
r2_dave <- function(y, yhat, ybar){
  num <- sum((y - yhat)^2)
  den <- sum((y - ybar)^2)
  return(1 - (num/den))
}
r2s_sklearn <- r2s_dave <- rep(NA, ncv)
for (i in 1:ncv){
  
  idx <- sample(
    seq(1, length(x), 1),
    n_train,
    replace = F
  )
  
  x_train <- x[idx]
  y_train <- y[idx]
  x_test <- y[-idx]
  y_test <- y[-idx]
  
  L <- lm(y_train ~ x_train)
  yhat <- (coef(L) %*% t(cbind(1, x_test)))[1, ]
  
  r2s_sklearn[i] <- r2_sklearn(y_test, yhat)
  r2s_dave[i]    <- r2_dave(   y_test, yhat, mean(y_train))

  
}
d_sklearn <- data.frame(
  R2 = r2s_sklearn,
  CDF = ecdf(r2s_sklearn)(r2s_sklearn),
  Calculation = "Scikit-learn"
)
d_dave <- data.frame(
  R2 = r2s_dave,
  CDF = ecdf(r2s_dave)(r2s_dave),
  Calculation = "Dave"
)
d <- rbind(d_dave, d_sklearn)
ggplot(d, aes(x = R2, y = CDF, col = Calculation)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


When you look at the distribution functions for $75$ iterations of training and then testing on unseen data, indeed, the $R^2$ calculation from sklearn is typically negative. This is consistent with what you observe in your Python code.
The reason you observe negative values of $R^2$ is that sklearn does not calculate $R^2$ by squaring anything. As I discuss here, sklearn calculates according to the following.
$$
R^2_{\text{out-of-sample, scikit-learn}}=
1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y_{\text{input-}y}
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
If the numerator of the fraction exceeds the denominator, the entire calculation is negative, revealing the model to have worse performance (in terms of square loss measures like MSE and RMSE) than that of a simple benchmark that always predicts the mean of the input data.
Such a calculation makes for a simple API, but I believe it lacks a useful interpretation when it comes to out-of-sample data, as I discuss in that same link, and I would go with an out-of-sample $R^2$ calculation as follows.
$$
R^2_{\text{out-of-sample, Dave}}=
1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y_{\text{in-sample}}
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
That gives the red "Dave" line in the plot, which is mostly positive. Indeed, the sklearn calculation can be rigorously shown to be a lower bound on my calculation. (This exercise is useful.)
A possible explanation for why you get any $R^2$ values below zero is what happens when you leave out a particular point, the one at the top right.
d_data <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(d_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()


One the entire data set, the correlation is fairly high, almost $0.7$ for a linear regression $R^2$ around $0.49$. However, dropping that one point via cor(x[y < max(y)], y[y < max(y)]) drops the correlation to a much lower value around $0.41$ for a linear regression $R^2$ score of $0.16$. The trend is much weaker when that one point is omitted, which will happen four of the five times in your cross-validation. If the other points in the training sample lead to a fairly flat or negative-sloped regression line, that top point will be predicted very poorly, with a corresponding high penalty to the square loss and a low, evidently even negative, $R^2$ value, particularly when you use the sklearn calculation that is a lower bound on the calculation I prefer.
(Again, that link of mine gets into why I prefer my calculation, including a reference to the literature that argues in favor of my stance. (The reference is not my paper.)
